# C program - find largest sequence in array

Tags: c, arrays

Given this example :

```
int arr[3][7] = {       {1,0,0,1,1,1,1},  //should output 4
                        {0,1,1,1,1,0,1},  //should output 4
                        {0,0,1,1,1,1,1}}; //should output 5
```

Find the largest sequence containing number **1**, and print line index and number of **1**.

*Do not count total numbers of* **1** *in each line. Only if they are one after another*.

here is my approach :

```
int main(){
    int i,j,c=0,count=0;

    int arr[3][7] = {   {1,0,0,1,1,1,1},  //output 4
                        {0,1,1,1,1,0,1},  //output 4
                        {0,0,1,1,1,1,1}}; // output 5

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<7; j++){
            if(arr[i][j] == 1){
                c++;
            } else if( arr[i][j] == 0 && c > count ) {
                count = c;
                c = 0;
            }
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
    }

  return 0;
}
```

**What i want to get as output now is 4,4,5 but i am getting 1,4,5.**

**SOLUTION** thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/users/1228887/twain249

```
int main(){
    int i,j,c=0,count=0;

    int arr[3][7] = {   {1,1,0,1,1,1,1},  //output 4
                        {0,1,1,1,1,0,1},  //output 4
                        {0,0,1,1,1,1,1}}; // output 5

    for(i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(j=0; j<7; j++){
            if(arr[i][j] == 1){
                c++;
            } else {
                count = c;
                c = 0;
            }
        }
        if(c > count){
            count = c;
        }
        printf("%d\n", count);
        c=0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Learn how to debug your small programs https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: @zerkms i am beginner in C language and do not know how to write test functions properly.

Comment: The article also mentions a debugger. If you tried to debug your code you'd spot the problem instantly.

Comment: Your solution fails case like this `{ 1,1,1,0,1,1,0 }` returns 2 instead of 3

Comment: @KillzoneKid yes, the answer below fixed the case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to handle the case where the longest sequence is the end of the list

after the inner `j` loop add the following

```
if (c > count) {
    count = c;
}
```

Also you forgot to add a clear after each check.

After the printout add

```
c = clear = 0;
```

EDIT: 1 more error. You need to reset `c` even if the new sequence isn't the longest.

Change the else if into

```
else if (arr[i][j] == 0) { // If isn't necessary if 0/1 are your only options
{
    if (c > count) {
        count = c;
    }
    c = 0;
}
```

Comment: i think if statement inside else is not neccessary since c variable is reseted if it catches an 0.